# Recording performance with Chrome devtools timeline using automation

Tags: angularjs, performance, google-chrome, protractor, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently trying to write some meaningful performance tests for an Angular application. I use protractor for my e2e tests and am currently using [protractor-perf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-perf). While it's helpful in identifying that a performance issue exists, it's impossible to actually identify what's causing the performance issues. However you can identify the source of the problem manually by using chrome devtools to record a timeline/profile and either inspect the result or save the file for future use. 
I'm wondering if there is anyway to automate the recording of a timeline or profile and save the file for future analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This repository by Paul Irish: https://github.com/paulirish/automated-chrome-profiling may be of use to you. It uses the [Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-remote-interface) via a Web Socket.